# What is the name of this Italian pastry?

Tags: pastry

Italian pastry made at Christmas.

Ingredients:

- Eggs
- Flour
- Whiskey
- Sugar
- Vanilla
- Shortening

Then deep fried, and covered with powdered sugar are called "CRUSTELLIS" OR "CRUSTOLI".

Instead of powdered sugar they were also given a honey bath.  What is the name of the ones dipped in honey, is it "SCALEDEE"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean Strufoli.
It is indeed Italian and typical for Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean [chiacchiere](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiacchiere); the linked Wikipedia article mentions plenty of other names for them in different Italian regions.

Comment: Started to translate, but then I realized this was just copied from Wikipedia. I've replaced the bulk copied content with about what I think you were trying to say. No idea if it has anything to do with the honey-dipped ones the OP mentioned, though.